# Order of calling destroy() method on servlets/filters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, log4j, web.xml

I have a Java web app.

I can specify the order of calling `init()` method on servlets by the parameter in `web.xml`:

```
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

But, how can I specify the order of calling `destroy()` methods?

Actually, what I need to do is just shutdown log4j in the end.  But in advance I want to know if there is some rules for calling `destroy()` method.

Comment: Not an answer: If you have resources shared across Servlets to shut down, I'd use a ServletContext listener, which is called only once. So you do not depend on any 'strange' implicit shutdown sequence.

Comment: Why does log4j have to be shut down?

Comment: @Kevin Panko: Good question, maybe he/she uses some loggers logging to a database or queue, etc.?

Comment: If you do not shutdown log4j it will not release log files until app container is running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a look into the Servlet 3.0 spec. It does not define any rules on the order in which the `destroy` methods have to be called. Thus, it is not specified and you *should not* rely on any vendor specific behaviour. A second reason for not releasing resources shared across *Servlets* is, that a given Servlet can be destroyed at any time - if the container chooses to do so. See section 2.3.4 of Servlet 3.0 specification:

**2.3.4 End of Service**

*The servlet container is **not required to keep a servlet loaded** for any particular 
period of time. A servlet instance may be kept active in a servlet container for a 
period of milliseconds, for the lifetime of the servlet container (which could be a 
number of days, months, or years), or any amount of time in between.*

*When the servlet container determines that a servlet should be removed from 
service, **it calls the destroy method** of the Servlet interface to allow the servlet to 
release any resources it is using and save any persistent state. For example, the 
container may do this when it wants to conserve memory resources, or when it is 
being shut down*

Let's say you have 3 Servlets - A, B, and C. If A and B rely on resources managed by C, it may happen that the container decides to temporarily disable C by calling its `destroy` method. So A and B won't have access to those resources any more. I must admit, I've never seen this behaviour in reality.

**Recommendation:**

Use a [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). It is guaranteed to be initialized and destroyed only once.